# php array to csv conversion with column headers

Tags: php

I want to convert array to csv ,im able to convert the associative array to csv.

But not able to get the headers.

I want the NUMBER TYPE DATE as headers dynamically

Below is the array i converrted .

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NUMBER] => 67
            [TYPE] => Other
            [DATE] => 3/31/2011
        )
     [1] => Array
          (
            [NUMBER] => 87
            [TYPE] => something
            [DATE] => 3/28/2011


          )
     [2] => Array
          (
            [NUMBER] => 67
            [TYPE] => Other
            [DATE] => 3/2/2011


          )

)
```

The code is given below .But not able to get the headers but its values are coming.

```
<?
 $fp1 = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($arr2 as $fields) 
{
    fputcsv($fp1, $fields);
}

fclose($fp1);
?>
```

Comment: use [`array_keys`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function at the beginning to put in the headers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) to get the keys and write them to the file first.

```
fputcsv($han, array_keys($arr[0]));
foreach ($arr as $a) { ... }
```

This assumes that you have a numeric array though (and it assumes that it's not empty). If `arr[0]` is not guaranteed to be set, you can use [`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift) or [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) to extract the first element. (Or you could just have a flag in your loop of whether or not the header is already written -- just have it default to false. If it's not true, set it to true and print the header.)

---

While I'm at it, you can use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) to go the opposite direction (CSV to array of associative arrays).

```
$data = array();
$header = fgetcsv($han);
while (($row = fgetcsv($han)) !== false) {
    $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}
```

(Note that this assumes you have no blank rows -- a blank row would return `array()` which will issue a warning with the combine and put non-sense into `data`.)

Comment: Your csv to array code will fail if one of the data rows is not the same length as the header.

Answer (score 10):

DarrenK 's answer is readable but incomplete. So for the noephytes.

```
    $pathToGenerate = 'array.csv';  // your path and file name
    $header=null;
    $createFile = fopen($pathToGenerate,"w+");
    foreach ($array as $row) {

        if(!$header) {

            fputcsv($createFile,array_keys($row));
            fputcsv($createFile, $row);   // do the first row of data too
            $header = true;
        }
        else {

            fputcsv($createFile, $row);
        }
    }
    fclose($createFile)
```

Answer (score 2):

Robert Clark's answer is very close, but still needs simplification:  There's no need for the `else` clause:

```
    $pathToGenerate='array.csv';    // your path and file name
    $header=FALSE;
    $createFile=fopen($pathToGenerate,'w+');
    foreach ($array as $row)
    {   if (!$header)
        {   fputcsv($createFile,array_keys($row));
            $header=TRUE;
        }
        fputcsv($createFile,$row);   // write the data for all rows
    }
    fclose($createFile);
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked nicely for me
null $header will not be null once you assign the keys then the rows will follow.

```
$header=null;
$createFile = fopen($pathToGenerate,"w+");
foreach ($assocArray as $row) {
    if(!$header){
        fputcsv($createFile,array_keys($row));
    }else{
    fputcsv($createFile, $row);
    }
}
fclose($createFile);
```

not as short as above but I find it quite readable.

Comment: This doesn't write the first row of the data to the file, only the header.  It also doesn't change the value of `$header` so the headers will be repeated for every row of data, never writing any actual data.